# Sympy NSolve (11 simultaneous eqns) gives ZeroDivisionError: matrix numerically singular

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am trying to solve 11 non-linear simultaneous equations with 11 unknowns, using Sympy Nsolve. I know that there is definitely a solution to the equations because I have solved the equations in another way and it works, so the values in the arguments are correct and should converge to a solution.

However, when I run the code I get the error ZeroDivisionError: matrix is numerically singular. What does it mean and what should I do? Note: the right answer for all the solutions should be positive and real.

````
###importing
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym


###defining argument values
Cpz= 2 #argument
intensity= 0.0499717154066123 #argument
length = 10 #argument
Ax, Ay, Az, Bx, By, Bz, Cx, Cy, Cz, Dx, Dy, Dz = 0, length, 0, length, length,0,  0, 0, 0, length, 0, 0
ni, nm= 1.1, 1 #argument


#defining symbols
thetaC1= sym.symbols("thetaC1", real= True)
thetaC2= sym.symbols("thetaC2", real= True)
Cpx= sym.symbols("Cpx", real= True)
Px= sym.symbols("Px", real= True)
Pz= sym.symbols("Pz", real= True)
Cphorizdist= sym.symbols("Cphorizdist")
Cpvertdist= sym.symbols("Cpvertdist")
Cpdist3D= sym.symbols("Cpdist3D")
Chorizdist= sym.symbols("Chorizdist")
Cvertdist= sym.symbols("Cvertdist")
Cdist3D= sym.symbols("Cdist3D")

#defining equations
eq1= sym.Eq(sym.asin((nm/ni)*sym.sin(thetaC2)), thetaC1) 
eq2= sym.Eq(np.absolute(Px-Cpx), Cphorizdist) 
eq3= sym.Eq(np.absolute(Cpz-Cz), Cpvertdist) 
eq4= sym.Eq(( (Cphorizdist)**2 + (Cpvertdist)**2 )**(1/2), Cpdist3D)
eq5= sym.Eq(np.absolute(Cpx-Cx), Chorizdist)
eq6= sym.Eq(np.absolute(Cpz-Cz), Cvertdist)
eq7= sym.Eq((Chorizdist**2 + Cvertdist**2)**(1/2), Cdist3D) 
eq8= sym.Eq(Cphorizdist/Cpdist3D, sym.sin(thetaC1)) 
eq9= sym.Eq(Cpx/Cdist3D, sym.sin(thetaC2))
eq10= sym.Eq(Chorizdist/2, sym.tan(thetaC2)) 
eq11= sym.Eq(1/((Cpdist3D+Cdist3D)**2),intensity)


result = sym.nsolve((eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq8,eq9,eq10,eq11),
(thetaC1,thetaC2,Cpx,Cphorizdist,Cpvertdist,Cpdist3D,Chorizdist,Cvertdist,Cdist3D,Px,Pz),
(0.3,0.6,1.0,1.3,1.6,1.9,2.3,2.6,2.9,3.3,3.6), verify= False, maxsteps= 50000)
print(f"thetaC1,thetaC2,Cpx,Cphorizdist,Cpvertdist,Cpdist3D,Chorizdist,Cvertdist,Cdist3D,Px,Pz is {result}")```
````

Comment: A matrix is singular if its determinate is zero. It means that it doesn't have an inverse. As for what to do, double check your coefficients and compute the determinate. If the coefficients are correct and the determinate is zero, there isn't much more you can do

Comment: @sizzzzlerz The thing is the error message goes away when I pass an actual value of 4 into Pz, which makes me think the problem is with the solving algorithm and not with my coefficients

Comment: Your equations don't contain Pz so it isn't possible to solve for Pz and also the Jacobian will always be singular because the Pz column is just all zero.